# Exploratory factor analysis based on separated constructs before CB-SEM?

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, exploratory-data-analysis

I've seen a paper where the researcher developed a modified version of the UTAUT2 theoretical model. This modification means that 5 new constructs have been added (from the literature), so the model had 10 constructs or latent variables overall.

[image: Model]

The researcher named three aspects (according to the colors). The constructs included in the aspects were not from the same sources. Before performing a CB-SEM analysis, the researcher used EFA on a pilot study, hovewer it was performed three times, **for every aspects separately**. Also, right after EFA, a CFA and the assessment of discriminant and convergent validity was also performed **on the same pilot dataset**, before moving to the final dataset and performing (just) the CB-SEM.
The literature I've found have a mixed opinion about this process, so I thought it would be better to discuss before developing a proper pipeline for my research.

- Is it right to spearate the construct based on personal opinion and performing the EFA seraparely like in the mentioned research? I suppose it is not a correct way, but some feedback would be much appreciated.
- I've read that performing both EFA and CFA on the same dataset is not a good idea. But is it acceptable if the EFA is performed on the pilot dataset and the CFA is performed on the final dataset before moving to CB-SEM?
- Is it acceptable to perform discriminant and convergent validity checks on the pilot dataset, but not on the final dataset (which was the case in the mentioned research)? I assume it is also wrong, but again, some feedback would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much for any constribution!